# I am working in embedded development using rust and tried to use itm but its not getting installed

Tags: rust, embedded, rust-cargo

Hi i was working with discovery book and I was trying to install the itmdump but it's showing me error.

> error: there is nothing to install in itm v0.3.1, because it has no binaries cargo install is only for installing programs, and can't be used with libraries. To use a library crate, add it as a dependency in a Cargo project instead

```
rustc Version
rustc 1.55.0-nightly (2f391da2e 2021-07-14)
cargo --version
cargo 1.55.0-nightly (3ebb5f15a 2021-07-02)
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: So the error says all that you need - add the library as a dependency in `Cargo.toml`, then use the library in your Rust code

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov, the problem is that the `itm` package *is supposed to have a binary program in it!*

Comment: … I would also note that the binary program was deleted on master, but it is present in the v0.3.1 tag, and that ‘should’ be what gets pulled from crates.io.

Comment: @Samar, either way, if you show an error message, always make sure you also provide the exact command that produced it as it is possible (and quite likely) that you have the wrong command or that you have a typo in it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue with

```
cargo --version
cargo 1.55.0-nightly (495297903 2021-07-01)
rustc --version
rustc 1.55.0-nightly (798baebde 2021-07-02)
```

I just run

```
cargo install itm
    Updating crates.io index
    Downloaded itm v0.3.1
    Downloaded 1 crate (15.6 KB) in 2.00s
    Installing itm v0.3.1
    ... compiling some more crates
```

After that

```
itmdump --version
    itmdump 0.3.1
```

You can try and report the issue in the [official repository](https://github.com/rust-embedded/itm) of `itm`

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this I just use `rm -rf ~/.cargo/registry` (wipes Cargo's download cache and some meta information) then this `cargo install itm` worked.